# How to call a stored procedure(PostgreSQL) with Spring JPA?

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

PostgreSQL Procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.create_task_by_device(task_id integer, device_ids text)
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $procedure$
    begin
        -- do something here
    END;
$procedure$
;
```

Spring JPA:(Kotlin)

```
interface TaskTemplateRepository : JpaRepository<TaskTemplate, Int> {
    @Procedure("public.create_task_by_device")
    fun createTaskByDevice(@Param("task_id") taskId: Int, @Param("device_ids") device_ids: String)
}
```

Exception:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: public.create_task_by_device(integer, character varying) is a procedure. To call a procedure, use CALL.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2553) ~[postgresql-42.2.20.jar:42.2.20]
```

Then I got the SQL statement executed `{call public.create_task_by_device(?,?)}` by `spring.jpa.show-sql: true`

It seems that the statement actually executed is `call` using call.

I don't understand why the whole sentence is surrounded by `{ ... }`

Then I tried to single-step debugging, the SQL statement actually executed in the `org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement#execute` method is `select * from create_task_by_device(1,'2') as result`, unlike the SQL statements output by JPA on the command line, I don't know why

[image: debug picture]

Finally, I try to write my own SQL statement

```
    @Query("call public.create_task_by_device(?1, ?2)", nativeQuery = true)
    fun createTaskByDevice(@Param("task_id") taskId: Int, @Param("device_ids") device_ids: String)
```

I got another exception `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: No results were returned by the query.`

If I add `@Modifying` in the method, throws `javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing to @Query with : as place holder -> (:task_id,:device_ids);

```
@Query(value = "{call public.create_task_by_device(:task_id,:device_ids)}",nativeQuery = true)
```

If SP performs a DML operation like (**Insert,Update**) add following annotations along with @Query;

```
@Transactional 
@Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)
```

Heres a reference -> https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-stored-procedures#query-annotation

Comment: it throws `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: No results were returned by the query.`

Comment: What kind of operation does the SP perform a DQL or DML ?

Comment: I updated my answer to point to the exception your referring to.

Comment: thx, it's works for me. Remind others that if there is a `commit` in a stored procedure, an exception will be thrown `PSQLException: ERROR: invalid transaction termination`. Reference: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-call.html

Comment: @forDream if your procedure calls `commit` use `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)`. It will still do any usual setup like `set search_path ...` etc but won't start an explicit transaction before the call.