# How to call procedure from PostgreSQL in Spring Boot

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot

In Spring Boot (language used is Java), I have written like this to call procedure from PostgreSQL.

```
String sqlQuery = "{CALL SP_GENERATE_OTP(?,?,?,?,?)}";
```

Is this correct way to call procedure? Please help me to solve this error.

Comment: check if this answer works for you https://stackoverflow.com/a/54753891/6228210 or [using query annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68030744/6228210)

Comment: its not working

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54732196/cant-call-postgresqls-11-stored-procedure-with-hibernate

Comment: i had tried this also still getting error

Comment: Nope, this is just a String assignment. And "its not working" is the worst possible description of an error. Please post your complete code and the precise error message.